# Grafana Alerts with Graphs

Tags: grafana

I'm trying out Grafana's alert and notificaiton feature, and it looks really awesome.

*Sample slack notification.*

[image]

However there is a big problem. It needs to be configured with S3, which makes the images publicly accessible to anybody. Is there a way to make this feature secure for companies that does not want their images publicly accessible?

http://docs.grafana.org/guides/whats-new-in-v4/

> Notifications
>   Alerting would not be very useful if there was no way to send notifications when rules trigger and change state. 
>   You can setup notifications of different types. We currently have Slack, PagerDuty, Email and Webhook with more in the pipe that will be added during beta period. 
>   The notifications can then be added to your alert rules.
>
> If you have configured an **external image store in the grafana.ini config file (s3 and webdav options available)**
>   you can get very rich notifications with an image of the graph and the metric values all included in the notification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what notifications you are using and how much security you want.

Posting the images to a webdav server you can pretty much make all those security decisions yourself.

Email notifications Grafana will fallback to attaching those images in the email message if the external images store is not configured.